# Are wild dogs really a problem in Samoa?

Tags: safety, nature-and-wildlife, oceania, samoa

Of all the dangers to worry about when visiting a foreign country, I did not consider packs of stray dogs roaming the streets and attacking people. But apparently this is a thing:

> Stray dogs are a problem in Samoa. Do not approach or feed them as they can become aggressive.

-- http://travel.gc.ca/destinations/samoa

> The biggest danger tourists face is not from humans, but rather from dogs, who roam in packs and can get very aggressive. The risk of a dog attack should not be underestimated. Travel by taxi after dark and always carry a pointed object while out walking. If you find yourself surrounded, kneel down as if you are picking up a rock.

-- http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Samoa

I did a little searching after reading the second one (the first stuck in my head as such an unusual thing to warn about) but haven't been able to find anything else other than forum posts asking if it's a problem.

Samoa is "on the bubble" for this trip and the dog situation could tip the balance. I would like to know if it's really something to worry about or not.

Comment: As somebody who likes to hitchhike alone all around the world, often after dark, the only thing I answer when people asking me if I'm worried about safety is "dogs"! And I'm not even scared of dogs, but not being scared of them isn't enough to prevent you from getting bitten, and definitely won't prevent rabies. In fact I've never been bitten but came very close once in Mexico and once in Georgia and have seen plenty of feral dogs in Central America and parts of Asia that would be worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are definitely a problem, with [over 200 dog bites treated at hospital in 2012](http://samoaobserver.ws/other/community/7714-dog-control-work-begins) (so not including any that weren't reported).  Samoa passed a law called [the Canine Control Act 2013](http://www.parliament.gov.ws/images/ACTS/Acts_2013/Canine_Control_Act_2013_-_Eng.pdf) last year to try and rectify some of the issues by implementing pounds, registration of dogs, and allowing destruction of diseased and/or aggressive dogs.  That should have an impact, but it wouldn't be immediate.